# Why is my VS Code having red highlighing of space characters even though I dont have errors there?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm still learning and I'm using VS Code, but somehow my IDE changed its colors and I'm not comfortable with it. I tried changing themes, but that doesn't seem to have an effect.

[image: Vs Code editor showing red highlights in spots with no characters]

Comment: Looks like some plugin is showing you spaces, where there shouldn't be any, like ESlint or something.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like the [`shardulm94.trailing-spaces`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=shardulm94.trailing-spaces) extension. Maybe you installed it by accident. It's highlighting trailing spaces (space characters at the ends of lines). You can configure it to remove trailing spaces on save. (you can also configure VS Code to do that too with `"files.trimTrailingWhitespace": true` in your settings.json file).

If you don't want it, uninstall or disable the extension. If you want to configure how it looks, you can do so in the settings.